# Need Help in Angular Routes

Tags: angular

I am Developing a small Angular Application with 3 pages

1. Login
2. Dashboard
3. User profile .

It is working fine , But the problem is , I dont want to have side bar in my login page . Means when i am in login page i should not see the sidebar. But when i am in other two pages i should be able to see the side bar . Can some body help to resolve this issue ?

Here the Route File

```
const routes: Routes =[
    { path: 'dashboard',      component: DashboardComponent },
    { path: 'user-profile',   component: UserProfileComponent },
    { path: 'login',   component: LoginComponent },
    { path: '',               redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
  ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

When I moved app.component.ts

```
public showMenu: boolean = false;

ngOnInit() {
   ...
   this.router.events.subscribe((event:any) => {

       if(event.url.split("/")[1] === 'login') {
           this.showMenu = false;
       } else {
           this.showMenu = true;
       }
       ...
   }
}
```

app.component.html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar" data-color='red' data-image="" *ngIf="showMenu">
        <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
        <div class="sidebar-background" style="background-image: url(../assets/img/sidebar-4.jpg)"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-panel">
        <app-navbar></app-navbar>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>

    </div>
</div>
```

I am Getting the Following Error Message :

[image]

Comment: You'll need to provide details around how your templates are set up to show the side bar.

Comment: Create sidebars as components and put tag inside the required pages

Comment: Here is my Code https://github.com/vmurali100/Angualar-Route

Comment: You can move your `<div class="sidebar" data-color='red' data-image="">
        <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
        <div class="sidebar-background" style="background-image: url(../assets/img/sidebar-4.jpg)"></div>
    </div>` present in app.component.html to your respective component's HTML

Comment: You can have nested router outlets to achieve what you want.  But really, for login, you should be using guards

Comment: Please choose more meaningful titles for your questions.

Comment: Have you checked the above solution?

Answer (score 0):

In app.component.ts add:

```
public showMenu: boolean = false;

ngOnInit() {
   ...
   this.router.events.subscribe((event:any) => {

       if(event.url.split("/")[1] === 'login') {
           this.showMenu = false;
       } else {
           this.showMenu = true;
       }
       ...
   }
}
```

app.component.html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar" data-color='red' data-image="" *ngIf="showMenu">
        <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
        <div class="sidebar-background" style="background-image: url(../assets/img/sidebar-4.jpg)"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-panel">
        <app-navbar></app-navbar>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>

    </div>
</div>
```

**Error with PerfectScrollbar**

Because you use the `sidebar` in `PerfectScrollbar`.I would remove this code - what I see it is useless at the moment or control and set the variable when it is visible.

```
  const elemSidebar = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.sidebar .sidebar-wrapper');
  ...
  elemSidebar.scrollTop = 0;
  ...
  ps = new PerfectScrollbar(elemSidebar);
```

If you want to use it then you have to change ngIf to style.display.

```
[style.display]="showMenu?'inherit':'none'
```

but then the element is not removed from the DOM but only hidden.

**STYLE**

Your layout leaves space for the menu - even though it does not exist. If you want you can change in template in app.component.html one line:

```
<div class="main-panel" [ngClass]="{'main-panel-login': !showMenu}">
```

And in app.component.css add

```
.main-panel-login {
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Please find the Image i have attached

Comment: I edited my answer. I would remove this part of the code. In my opinion, PerfectScrollbar is not used for your menu anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using **ngx-perfect-scrollbar** plugin in your app (version 4.9.0)

If you are using this, I think it will be related to the version issue of this plugin. May be the plugin version is not compatible with the Angular version.

Update 4.9.1 in your **package.json** and run **npm install**

Hope this solves the issue :)

Comment: "perfect-scrollbar": "1.1.0",         This is what you mean ?

Comment: Read that documentation & implement like that. For angular 4 and 5 this plugin is using.